# Remove parts of PHP string before echo

Tags: php

I am getting content from a database however this content isn't formatted correctly for what I am trying to achieve.

How data comes from the DB:

```
{"5":"The content"}
```

The number in the first set of `""` is different on each entry and not sequential.

I only need the content from this. what is the best way to remove the unwanted part of the string using PHP?

This is how I am currently displaying the content:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo $row["form_data"]. "<br>";
     }
} else {
     //empty message will be here
}
```

Comment: It looks like json so decode it and loop over the results or use something like `reset()` to get the value of the first / only element.

Comment: do you need `5` from `{"5":"The content"}`??

Comment: Is your `$row["form_data"]` contain `{"5":"The content"}`???

Comment: Check out this: [https://3v4l.org/7crtV](https://3v4l.org/7crtV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a JSON string, all you need to do is `json_decode()` that string

Use the second param of the `json_decode()` that converts the JSON to an array regardless of what it was defined as in JSON i.e. yours is an object, then you can simply use the `current` array syntax to get the content part regardless of what the number(`5`) is in any of this data.

```
$data = json_decode($row["form_data"], true);
echo current($data);
```

Comment: Don't echo `5`th index. Use `current`. Due to this *The number in the first set of "" is different on each entry and not sequential.*

Comment: @HankyPanky Good call, didn't think of that

Answer (score 1):

> Remove parts of PHP string before echo

No, actually don't.

```
{"5":"The content"}
```

is  **[JSON](http://The%20number%20in%20the%20first%20set%20of%20%22%22%20is%20different%20on%20each%20entry%20and%20not%20sequential.)**, go ahead [**decode**](http://php.net/json_decode) it to your like and take that number. There is no need to try to parse the string by some string manipulation.

Run this and you'll see

```
print_r(json_decode('{"5":"The content"}',true));
```

Rest of the code you can write yourself, don't need a copy paste answer right? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode` to make that, this is an example :

```
    $string = '{"5":"The content"}';
    $json = json_decode($string);
    var_dump($json->{'5'});
```

And the result is :

```
    string 'The content' (length=11)
```

If it's not 5 but you want the first record, you can make something like that :

```
    $string = '{"5":"The content", "6":"The"}';
    $json = json_decode($string);
    foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
        var_dump($value);
        exit;
    }
```

It will only print the first value

Or better, you can use `current()`

```
    var_dump(current($json));
```

Comment: And if it was not 5 someday then?